# How to obtain the source latex code of package documentation?

Tags: documentation

Is it possible to obtain the source latex code from package documentation? For example, I don't see the documentation latex file among [siunitx](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx) source files.

Comment: Ehm... Short answer: it's there. See [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=dtx) for a brief description.

Comment: Not: there is ongoing work on the `siunitx` package: look at `siunitx-v2.dtx`. More generally, look for the `.dtx` files in your TeX system (which should match your installed packages).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These files have the extension `.dtx`. The source for `siunitx` is [here](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.dtx). If you are using TeXLive, you can find the file on your own system by typing

```
kpsewhich siunitx.dtx
```

in the terminal.

Comment: Is this the source code to the package or to the documentation of the package? I'm looking for the latter.

Comment: It's both. See the link provided in @some1's comment.

Comment: @ipavlic In the case of `siunitx`, it's both: this is not required but is common for LaTeX packages as the `.dtx` format is designed to support such an approach.

Comment: Great, I see it now! Is there a built-in command to automatically strip non-documentation code (e.g. `\begin{macro}..`)?

Comment: @ipavlic What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JosephWright I liked the tables in your documentation, and wanted to see the source code. I found that. After that, I was just curious what else is possible.